# Difference between filtering with SQL syntax and calling the column explicitly in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I have a column (let's call it `X`) in my PySpark DataFrame that should be a `double` but is actually a `string`.  It contains values like, `["0.4", "0.0", "0.8", ...]`.

The entire dataframe has 24,968,894 rows.

When I filter using:

```python
df.where('X > 0.0')
```

I get 8,350,764 rows

But when I run:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.where(f.col('X') > 0.0)
```

I get 19,486,678 rows

I've done an anti-join between these two filtered dataframes to try and understand what is special about the rows that are dropped in the first method but notice nothing unusual.

Can anyone help me understand what is the difference between these two methods?

Also to be clear, I don't actually WANT to do this sort of thing--I hadn't realized this column was a string initially.  I'm just trying to understand WHY these two types of filtering are different when used this way.

Comment: Any chance  you could create a [mcve]?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think I can.  When I try to recreate this with just some toy data, it works as expected.  And I don't understand what is special about the rows that are filtered in my first example so that I could recreate this situation.  My hope is that someone could provide a high-level explanation of how the two filtering methods differ.

Comment: Can you add the execution plans for both?

Comment: Yes!  The execution plan casts column X as decimal(1,1) for the SQL syntax whereas it casts X as double for the `f.col('X') > 0.0` syntax.  Wow, that answers my question and is great to know.  Thank you, @pault !!

Answer (score 1):

Spark is casting column `X` as `decimal(1,1)` for the SQL syntax whereas it casts `X` as `double` for the `f.col('X') > 0.0` syntax*.

```python
df.where('X > 0.0').explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*Filter (isnotnull(X#202) && (cast(X#202 as decimal(1,1)) > 0.0))
#+- Scan ExistingRDD[X#202]

df.where(f.col("X") > 0.0).explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*Filter (isnotnull(X#202) && (cast(X#202 as double) > 0.0))
#+- Scan ExistingRDD[X#202]
```

*This may not be true in general, but that's what's happening in this particular case. Looking at the execution plan is the way to debug these types of issues.